# Symfony 2 Debug Bar only appears while I use built-in Web Server

Tags: php, symfony

My Project which is using Symfony 2 shows debug bar at the bottom of the page if I activate built-in web server through command `php app/console server:run`. But it doesn't appear when I open /web directory through local Web Server (I use Apache, XAMPP). Can anyone explain what's really happen? Thank you.

Comment: Just your webserver is not configured correctly, maybe rewrite rules.

Comment: are you sure you are using proper url? what front controller are you use: app.php or app_dev.php ?

Comment: Please post the apache configuration of your server, so that the community can check if it is set correctly. You can find it in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`

Comment: as far as I know there is only 2 reasons for Symfony to not show the debug bar:
- Your page dont have any body
- You use app.php instead of app_dev.php

Comment: After examining my webserver configuration, I found that there is nothing wrong. But thank you guys, I realize that app.php and app_dev.php were different. I change my .htaccess inside /web directory, I replace app.php with app_dev.php and symfony toolbar shows up.

Answer (score 0):

If your browser URL is just `/web` , your `/web/app.php` is executed, so you are in production environment.

To browse in dev mode, you have to add `/app_dev.php` after your `/web` folder, in browser URL.

Comment: After examining my webserver configuration, I found that there is nothing wrong. But thank you guys, I realize that app.php and app_dev.php were different. I change my .htaccess inside /web directory, I replace app.php with app_dev.php and symfony toolbar shows up.